# How to install php's gmp for windows?

Tags: laravel, php-gmp

- Root composer.json requires PHP extension ext-gmp * but it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gmp extension.

I'm getting this error, so can anyone tell me how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XAMPP:

```
;extension=gmp
```

Uncomment(remove ; from ;extension=gmp) this line in your php.ini file!

Comment: Done, still not working

Comment: Please restart XAMPP after changing ini file.